# how to keep checking if the EditText are empty (if empty button is enabled else is disabled) : android/java

Tags: java, android, xml

I have two EditText fields, and one button.

i want to do the following:

```
if the EditText1 && EditText2 == empty
   then
      button is disabled
     else
      button is disabled
```

the button should be enabled only if the user write something in both fields,

in simple words:

```
       if the user write something in both fields, the button will be enabeld,
```

if he delete what he write then disable the button again.

i will be regretful if any one answer me.

android 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

You want [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html). Use this to determine when text is changed in both. You could either do an 'if else' every time text is changed or in a while loop. Hope this helps. And I think you will be grateful not regretful for help :)